# Azure Data Factory : How to return a value from inside a Data Flow?

Tags: azure-data-factory

**A bit of context :**

- I need to set a **variable** as part of the output of my **pipeline**.
- that is easy to do if you use the **"Set Variable" activity** in the pipeline.

**Problem :**

- I cannot use the "set variable" activity.
- Reason: The value meant to go into the variable is computed **inside a Data Flow** called from the Pipeline.
- I don't know how to retrieve that value from the Data Flow, back into the caller pipeline.
- for information: the data flow outputs into a sink (a database). The pipeline merely calls the Data Flow. The value I'm interested in is a by-product of that Data Flow. Until now it was calculated inside of it and used inside of it. Now I need to pull it out of it.

**So, in summary :**

- How do you "return" a single value from a Data Flow that otherwise outputs to a sink, for that value to be used by the pipeline that called this data flow?

[image]

Comment: So your real question is "How to return a value from Data Flow", not how to set a variable. You'll get better views and responses with a more accurate question. To my knowledge, there is no direct way to do this, but you could have the Data Flow write the value to another Sink (like Blob Storage) and then read it with Lookup in the parent pipeline.

Comment: Or just use Lookup to get it after the Data Flow has run.

Comment: @wBob could you elaborate? A lookup on what? The sink of the data flow goes into a db. I'm a beginner to ADF, so from where I'm standing that data is "gone".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Dataflow(pass that variable data to the sink), use the lookup on the sink dataset to get that variable value in the pipeline as suggested by @**wBob**.

Adding to @**Joel Cochran**, You can use **sink cache** for the second sink.

First use a **conditional split** on your input data like below to get two branches of same data.

[image]

Give one of the branch to sink and give the **cache** like below.

[image]

In the original sink, transfer your data to target and the second sink is used for sink cache.
Give the sink write order for the dataflow.

[image]

In the dataflow activity, set the logging to **None** and uncheck the **First row only**.

[image]

In the dataflow activity output, you can see the second sink output array.

[image]

To access the above output array, use the below dynamic content in a set variable activity after the dataflow activity in the pipeline.

```
@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sinkcache.value
```

[image]

Later, you can use this array to get the data for your variable as per your requirement.

Comment: That's great! I didn't want to use a sink because I thought it was "dirty" to create a brand new CosmosDb container just to store a variable.... But then I didn't know that there were sinks of type "cache"! That's absolutely perfect. Thanks to you and @joel cochran. Before you wrote your answer I ended doing it with a Lookup and I'm currently banging my head against the wall to write the absolute simplest of expressions in the expression builder.