# Unsure how to use a ForEach Activity in a Data Pipeline to iterate over rows in a 2 column dataset derived from an API Json document

Tags: csv, foreach, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-pipeline

**PROBLEM CONTEXT**
I have successfully connected to an API and sent a request to an endpoint that returns rows of data as a Json array. This Json document is subsequently saved as a Json Dataset for downstream parsing and flattening. The data is finally transformed and saved as a 2 column csv Dataset.

The intent was then to use the 2 column csv Dataset as an input source of row data for a ForEach activity in the pipeline. Each iteration of the ForEach would then use the row property_id to send an API request to an enpoint that would return the details of an individual property. Then it would subsequently transform and save these details to the staging area of a data lakehouse database, using a stored procedure.

**THE PROBLEM**
I am new to the use of synapse and still learning what the best patterns, tools and techniques are for Ingesting, Transforming and Storing data for downstream analytics and machine learning workloads.

In this instance I am uncertain how I can iterate over the dataset to carry out the loop activities.

**SUPPORTING MATERIAL**
The raw API Json data is illustrated below:
[Data pipeline - Input API Json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFniZ.png)

The data pipeline is illustrated below for reference:
[Propert Ingestion Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL6jV.png)

The csv dataset produced by the Data flow Sink is illustrated below:
[Transform Etags Data Flow Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxeyY.png)

I tried to use the csv dataset as input to the ForEach activity and was uncertain as to how to acccomplish this. I was expecting that I could iterate over each row and extract the property_id and etag. And subsequently use the unique property_id on each iteration to call the API and return the detailed property details to be used in updating the staging area.

I have yet to be successfull in getting access to the relevant data on each iteration. Searching online has revealed many examples that use arrays as inputs to the ForEach activity, however I am unsure whether this even applies to my scenario.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

As you are storing the sink to a csv file, you can use lookup activity to get the JSON array from csv file.

After dataflow activity, add a lookup activity and give your sink csv file. You need to make sure your dataflow writes the output to single file. For that, go to **Dataflow sink settings** and select **Output to single file** in **File name option** and give your csv file name.

In lookup activity, give the csv dataset and uncheck the **First row only**.

[image]

Lookup activity will give the output like below JSON array.

[image]

You can use the below expression to give the above lookup array to Foreach.

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.value
```

[image]

Inside ForEach, you need to use `@item().property_id`, `@item().etag` to access the values.

If your csv size is less than 2 MB, instead of lookup, you can get the JSON array from Dataflow itself using **dataflow sink cache**.

Go through this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76153946/18836744) to understand about it.

**NOTE:** The dataflow cache sink's limitation is 2 MB and lookup activity output limitation is 4MB (5000 rows). If your csv file size is more than that, you need to use two level pipelines to iterate that.

So, first store your csv as part csv files (use partition number to get less size part files). Go to your sink settings and set the **File name option** to **Default**.

now, go to optimize and set the number of partitions.

[image]

This will give 2 part files in the sink folder. After the dataflow activity, you need to use Get meta data activity to get the part files list. Give this to ForEach and inside ForEach use lookup on every file. Use Execute pipeline after it and pass the lookup activity output as an array parameter to the child pipeline. Inside child pipeline use another ForEach and give the array parameter to it. This ForEach will iterate through each record in the file.

Go through this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74138488/18836744) by @**Pratik Lad** to understand about it.